# Obstructed/Incomplete quadrilateral detection with OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I want to detect quadrilateral with OpenCV.
Shape might not be in diffrent colour than surface. **e.g,** It could be a rectangle hole on the surface.

**My current approach works great when:**

- The object is on a plain surface with high color contrast on the edges.
- Edges are not obstructed.

**Here is my current pipeline:**

- Convert to Gray Scale
- Median Blur (GaussianBlur removes edge details)
- Canny edge detection with OTSU threshold values
- dilate & erode to fill small gaps
- Contour detection
- Filter out contours by min area, max points & roundness of shape
- `approxPolyDP` to get 4 points

**Problem with this approach:**

- When there is not much color contrast on the edges.
- There is a light reflection on the edge, it misses that portion of the edge
- When the object is in touch with another object or corner of the surface.

**Here is results for different scenarios:**

- [Work great when background is clearly seprated out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi8zU.jpg)
- [Edges are incomplete because of light reflaction or less color contrast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YVlv.jpg)
- [Edges are obstruced by something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkIyu.jpg)
- [Edges are conneted to other object and not seprately visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDleT.jpg)

***Note***: Here i have used an book as example. It could be any quadrilateral item even surface hole.

I have also tried with `HoughLine` approach but it results in too many lines and makes it impossible to filter lines related to rectangle. Followed [blog from DropBox](https://dropbox.tech/machine-learning/fast-and-accurate-document-detection-for-scanning#computing-intersections-and-scoring-quadrilaterals) but can't figur out how to filter rectanlge lines.

Please let me know if there is any better approach that solves these problems. Any lead will be helpful.

Comment: What is your actual goal finding these quadrilaterals maybe there can be other ways to achieve it. Do you need to calculate the are find the center or crop the image with the quadrilateral ? what do you do after finding the quadrilateral ? Can you control the lighting of the environment before you take the photos

Comment: This is a good and hard question i want to help if you explain it further.

Comment: @BarışAktaş Sure, let me clarify my objective.

I'm developing an AR Android application to identify quadrilateral hole on the surfaces, and then do further tasks with it.

- I aim to obtain the coordinates of the four corners of the quadrilateral, hole to be specific.
- The lighting conditions may vary and are beyond my influence.
- The surface and hole may have any color, identical or significant color contrast.
- I can’t get a better image but something like this [image](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/rectangular-hole-road-surface-filled-new-1133697965).

Comment: So you may focus on detecting the corners only. Because the shape is quadrilateral and the edges are not curves but lines, 4 corner will give you all the information you need. I once worked on a corner detection algorithm i will check my previous work on that. Idea was to first find all canditate corner points. Then check gray-levels of the four side of the detected candidate corner point and decide which corner it is (top-left, bot-right ..)

Comment: @BarışAktaş I have already tried [Good Features to Track](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d8c/tutorial_py_shi_tomasi.html) but it just detects too many points and I can't figure out how to get rectangle corners.

Comment: You are right. In your pipeline you can try bilateral Filtering instead of median or gaussian blur. Bilateral filter (`cv2.bilateralFilter()`) also takes color into account and its a better fit for preserving the edges.  https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html

Comment: @BarışAktaş Thanks for suggesting `bilateralFilter`. It's working quite well than other filters.

Comment: I looked a bit more for a solution but obsturcts on the shape  are tricky especially if they are on the corner the quadrilateral gets lost. You may work on your pipeline but i think the main problem is there are too many variaton, you should be able to minimize the light, position of the hole on cam view. Only then you may try to fit a line to each edge and intersect them to generate the quadrilateral.

Comment: @BarışAktaş I have the same thing implemented in iOS using their Vision framework [VNDetectRectanglesRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vndetectrectanglesrequest). It works perfectly for most of my cases. However, the results on Android with OpenCV are not as good as on iOS.

Comment: I dont use Hough Line detector too. Either i cant calibrate it properly or it returns too many faulse lines. Maybe a custom code for line detection will be better.